# Gibberish characters in Excel Export

Tags: java, file-io, character-encoding, export-to-excel

I'm getting gibberish characters in Exported excel from my web page

In ActionImpl.java

```
excelBean.setHeaders(Constants.VALUES);
```

In Constants.java

```
public static final String[] VALUES= { "Agrès"};
```

I should get - Agrès although i'm getting - AgrÃ¨s

Comment: Looks like what you would get with a basic character encoding mismatch. What API are you using to do the excel stuff?

Comment: There's not enough information in here to answer this question. What does a constant in your code have to do with Excel? What is the type of excelBean? What is the encoding of your source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `è` from "Agrès" as below:

1. Java source code: è to `\u00E8`   i.e. `Agr\u00E8s`
2. Using a HTML entity: è to `&#232;`  i.e. `Agr&#232;s`